# git merge changing the log output (not stable sort)

Tags: git

I've noticed that git merge doesn't seem to do a stable sort when it is doing a merge. Or it might be something totally different. I have really no idea what goes wrong.

If you try this small testcase a good 10-20 times, until it says "FLAKY":

```
mkdir a; cd a; output=$(git init .; touch 0; git add 0 ; git commit -m0; git checkout -b b1; touch 1; git add 1; git commit -m1; git branch b2 master; git checkout b2; touch 2; git add 2; git commit -m2; git checkout master; git merge b1; git merge b2 -m"merge";) test=$(git log --format=%s|xargs echo); if [[ "merge 2 1 0" == "$test" ]]; then echo "FLAKY " $test; else cd ..; rm -rf a; fi; 2> /dev/null
```

(it's a oneliner, you can run it in bash prompt)

Normally the log that you echo at the end will look like this:

```
merge 1 2 0
```

But after a while, you might get 1 and 2 to switch places:

```
merge 2 1 0
```

This is incredibly infuriating. I can always make those two first commits be interchangeable in the test, but I'd rather not. I'd rather remove the flakiness. Anyone know what causes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**: It's a race condition easy to trigger since git log sorts on time with 1 second resolution. A possible fix is to rather use:

```
git log --topo-order
```

---

So after looking into this. Git orders commits based on date/time. This is obvious. Date stored is in seconds since epoch, unix timestamp, so the resolution is horrible. When all commits have the same timestamp (the usual case), it will opt to sort them in some (stable!) order "merge 1 2 0".

However, sometimes, the last 2 happens *exactly* when the time changes, and so it will have a one-higher timestamp and will therefore always be placed above the 1.

So this is the common case:

```
Merge: a217d34 1f853fc
Date:   1381855683 +0200
    merge

commit a217d34c3b7694e4a5f963ead624b4d3e4a87adf
Date:   1381855683 +0200
    1

commit 1f853fc9acf669929ccab71d341784a525a5360e
Date:   1381855683 +0200
    2

commit 490507918504597c90300889aaf3cb5cbb5dd82c
Date:   1381855683 +0200
    0
```

This is the special (flaky) case. At least in this test, I guess it might be different in my real tests, there it flakes only when they suddenly have the same time.

```
Merge: a2f0bba f3b9f1e
Date:   1381855747 +0200
    merge

commit f3b9f1eeeef0c8c77aa8505224198951dc6d6904
Date:   1381855747 +0200
    2

commit a2f0bba815bb2a1e8e611f755397350c732b5e6b
Date:   1381855746 +0200
    1

commit ab28f3063df4d51c79ee0fbdec0ae77f870e8e3b
Date:   1381855746 +0200
    0
```

I have not yet devised what plan I will follow to fix this, but it seems like `git log --topo-order` will do. It behaves the same for this small test at least.